# Get all dates for a specific day of week (e.g. Monday) between 2 dates

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

Consider given 2 dates between 2015-01-01 and 2015-01-30, I need to find the dates for every Monday and every Sunday during that period.

I have a report, the user needs to select a date range, and from the date range it calculates each first-day-of-week and last-day of week and passes it in that way.

How it currently works in SSRS is

```
exec storedprocname
@BD=N'798211,798654,798664,798826',
@CGNo=N'47',
@SCGNo=N'4701,4702,4703,4704,4705,4706,4707,4708',
@ProductClass=N'1,2,4,3',
@ProductCode=N'1020',
@Region=N'772',
@FirstDayOfWeek='2014-01-06 00:00:00',
@LastDayOfWeek='2014-01-12 00:00:00'
```

User selects multiple Mondays and Sundays, the report is a matrix table and matrix's on first day of week

> FirstdayOfWeek = '2014/06/09,2014/06/16'
>
> LastdayOfWeek = '2014/06/15,2014/06/23'

What I need is a date range the user selects this and it will still pass it in the same way

> @startdate '2015/01/01' = Thursday (for this select current week's Monday)
>
> @startdate '2015/02/01' = Sunday

Comment: you tagged this as MySQL code but it seems like SQL Server code.

Comment: what query result you want to get ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SSRS inbuilt function `WEEKDAYNAME`

```
=WEEKDAYNAME(DATEPART("dw", Fields!myDate.Value)
```

OR

```
=WEEKDAYNAME(DATEPART("w", Fields!myDate.Value)
```

You can use weekdayname function to filter your dataset or matrix or use in Iff expression.

If you want to handle it in SQL Server you can use [dataname](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395(v=sql.110).aspx) function.